# 仮想マシン上のCoreOSで、dockerの永続化データをホストとの共有フォルダに作成できず、権限エラーとなってしまう

Tags: mysql, macos, vagrant, docker, coreos

色々検索してみたものの、同種の問題が見つけられなかったので質問いたします。

vagrantで構築したCoreOSにホストとの共有フォルダを設定し、公式のmysqlコンテナを実行させようとしているのですが、どうしても上手く構築ができません。

ホストにある `mysql` ディレクトリを `/home/core/share/` 以下にマウントした状態で次のコマンドを実行すると、

```
$ docker -run -v /home/core/share/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

起動途中でパーミッションが変更できないというエラーが表示されていまいます。

```
FATAL ERROR: Could not chown directory /var/lib/mysql/
```

`-v` オプションの指定先を、共有フォルダ以外のパスに指定した場合は問題なく最後まで起動しました。CoreOS内でアクセス権限の変更も試してみましたが、解決しません。

```
# やったけど解決せず
$ chown core:core /home/core/share/mysql
```

- Vagrantfileは公式のものからファイル共有部分をコメントアウト(124行目)して作成しています。
  https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant/blob/master/Vagrantfile
- ホストはMacOSX Yosemiteにvagrantとvirtualboxをインストールしています。

もしかして、共有フォルダに直接永続化データを作成するような使い方はできないような仕組みになっているのでしょうか…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決したので報告します。

CoreOSのVagrantfileに書いてあるファイル共有設定では、プロトコルとしてNFSが使用されます。(この場合はMacOSXのnfsdを使用)

NFSを使ったファイル共有では、クライアント側からはchownできません。
そのため、どうしてもchownが必要な場合、次の2つのアプローチのいずれかをとる必要があるようです。

- NFSサーバ側で、dockerコンテナ側のUID/GIDに合わせてあらかじめオーナーを変更しておく
- dockerコンテナ側のUID/GIDを、NFSサーバ側のオーナーに合わせて構成しておく

既存のdockerコンテナの構成をいじるのは面倒なので、前者のアプローチを採用しました。

公式のmysqlコンテナの場合、普通に起動すると/var/lib/mysql以下のオーナーは 999:999 になっている為、MacOSXのターミナル上で共有したいフォルダへあらかじめ`$chown -R 999:999 target`をしておきます。この状態でmysqlコンテナを立ち上げたところ、問題なく初期化処理を通過することができました。

Comment: さらに補足。色々考えると、現状Dockerコンテナ内の永続化データをVirtualBox越しにスムーズにホスト(MacOSX)と共有する方法はなさそうに思います。色々なDockerコンテナで初期化時にオーナーやパーミッションの変更を永続化データに対して行っており、都度NFSのパーミッションの問題に引っかかってしまうためです。仮想マシンに永続化データが貼り付いてしまうのはVagrantの良さを殺してしまうため、本当はやりたくないのですが…。

もし新たな方法を発見したら追記します。

Answer (score 1):

ホストがOS Xとのことで、ちょっと触ったことがないので確かなことは言えませんが、
windowsとcentOSの場合でも、パーミッションの問題はよくあるので、環境の問題かもしれませんね。
本来であればデータの永続化は可能です。だた、昔PATH(/usr/local/bin等)をマウントしようとしたときに私も失敗したような気がします。
mysqlの実データをマウント、ということ自体あまりよくないようがしますので、コンテナ作成時にポートフォワードしてはいかがですか？

ホスト側でmysqlが起動しているのであればdockerからポートフォワードで接続できます。

```
docker -run -v /home/core/share/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mysql -p 13306:3306
```

実際の接続はdockerに接続してから

```
mysql -u root --port=13306 database
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。例がmysqlなのが悪かったと思うのですが、永続化データが仮想マシンに溜まっていくのが嫌で、できるだけホスト側のファイルシステムを参照させて使いたかったというのが質問の意図でした。  

他のdockerイメージを使ったときも、ホストとファイル共有しているディレクトリはことごとくchownに失敗してしまった為、永続化データはCoreOS内に溜めて定期的にホスト側でダンプをとるなり、CoreOS内からファイル同期をとる方針で使おうと思っています。